# Visual Studio 2012 "Step into" wrong function and Breakpoints not hit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a Xamarin project and when I make an instance of a certain class a bearkpoint inside the constructor never gets hit. Just after instancing the class i call for a function of that class and the Step Into functionality of visual studio 2012 sends me to another totally unrelated function of another class.

When I comment that unrelated function that the Step Into sends me to and call the function again, the Step Into sends me again to a totally unrelated function of another third class.

The functions don't even have the same name.

I already cleaned, rebuild, manuallly deleted bin and obj and nothing works.

Any one knows what is happening?

Note: the Go To Definition (F12) command works as expected but the Step Into (F11) doesn't. I also have it on Debug mode instead of Release.

Comment: @Jacob, Try reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the problem here is obviously your debug symbols are out of sync with your source files. A few ways this can happen:

- you're not actively building debug symbols (thus relying on older leftovers), or have optimizations enabled. Note that simply having the debug configuration selected doesn't mean this is not the case -- "debug" is just a label, you can name it puppies for all VS cares. Check the settings.
- it's possible there's conflicts with the GAC or the symbol server trying to download wrong symbols. Check your file names that they're not too similar to system DLLs.
- You mentioned Xamarin -- I'd triple check that it has the right symbols. It's possible following the call stack through out of date Xamarin symbols is screwing up things when it comes out and back into your code (events).

Another thing I'd try is to cold start your executable, then attach through VS. Go line by line in the Output window and see which symbols are loaded, and equally important, which are failing to load. Check your output folder, check the .pdb file names. Make sure you're not confusing things with the .vshost.exe file, you only care about the executable and any DLLs of your own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How do you check that Xamarin has the right symbols?